# mybatis mulidatasource in springboot with the problem 'more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates'

Tags: spring, mybatis

This problem that 'more than one "primary" bean found among candidates' always occurs when I configure mybatis multiple data sources in springboot.

**the master data sources is configured as follows：**

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.monkey.myproject.dao.first", sqlSessionTemplateRef = "sqlSessionTemplate1")
public class DataSourceConfig1 {
    @Bean(name = "dataSource1")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.first")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource1() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionFactory1")
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory1(@Qualifier("dataSource1") DataSource dataSource1) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource1);
        bean.setMapperLocations(
                new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:/mapper/first/*.xml"));
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager1")
    @Primary
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager1(@Qualifier("dataSource1") DataSource dataSource1) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource1);
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionTemplate1")
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate1(@Qualifier("sqlSessionFactory1") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory1)
            throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory1);
    }
}
```

**the slave data sources is configured as follows：**

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.monkey.myproject.dao.second", sqlSessionTemplateRef = "sqlSessionTemplate2")
public class DataSourceConfig2 {
    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.second")
    public DataSource dataSource2() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionFactory2")
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory2(@Qualifier("dataSource2") DataSource dataSource2) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource2);
        bean.setMapperLocations(
                new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:/mapper/second/*.xml"));
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager2")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager2(@Qualifier("dataSource2") DataSource dataSource2) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource2);
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionTemplate2")
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate2(@Qualifier("sqlSessionFactory2") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory2)
            throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory2);
    }
}
```

**The Junit Test is as follows：**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sqlSessionTemplate1")
private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate1;
@Test
public void test2() {
    try {
        sqlSessionTemplate1.insert("FirstMapper.insertOne", null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When this test is executed, the exception message appears,as follows：

```
more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [primaryDataSource, secondaryDataSource, dataSource1, dataSource2]
```

note:When I remove this annotation '@Primary' from master,This test case passes.but that is why?please help me,thank you in advance.

Comment: this is a springboot project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this issue caused by Spring Auto Configuration, which accompany almost every Spring Starter. And it's kinda weird that devs mark their beans with `@Primary` annotation.

So you could turn it off using `application.properties` file:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Or with following annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration::class])
or
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration::class])
```